# Center navigation

Tags: css, navigation, center

I've searched the forum and tried a lot of the suggestions that were already made, but I can't seem to center my site navigation.

I'm using a website builder with access to the CSS, so my knowledge is somewhat limited. I would like to maintain the same width of the navigation across the page, but I would prefer for the actual navigation selections to be centered.

Does anyone have any suggestions (preferably simply suggestions since I don't really know what I'm doing). Here is my CSS:

```
  .sf_navigation {
    clear:both;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:auto;
    min-height:38px;
    height:auto!important;
    height:38px;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:13px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1000;
}

.sf_navigation ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    height:1%;
}

.sf_navigation ul li {
    margin:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}

.sf_navigation ul li a {
    display:block;
    font-weight:700;
    padding:12px 37px 0;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-right:solid 0;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    height:25px;
    width:auto!important;
    white-space:nowrap;
    width:1%;
}

.sf_navigation ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    position:relative;
}

.sf_navigation:after,.sf_navigation ul:after {
    content:".";
    display:block;
    visibility:hidden;
    height:0;
    clear:both;
}

.sf_navigation .widget_header {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle.net with the html :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to `sf_navigation` CSS

`.sf_navigation {
display: table;
}`

Comment: Tried adding display:table; but it didn't seem to change anything...?